Как отключить ssl в tyrus
Пытаюсь сделать client для back. Выдает ошибку с ключами. Возник вопрос, возможно ли отключить ssl в tyrus.

Использую libs

javax.websocket-client-api-1.1.jar
tyrus-standalone-client-1.9.jar

Смотрел в doc, "Tyrus 2.1.5 User Guide" и данный пример не сработал (8.1.1. Host verification). Пробовал версию tyrus 2.1.5
Tyrus 2.1.5 User Guide

SslEngineConfigurator sslEngineConfigurator = new SslEngineConfigurator(new SslContextConfigurator());
sslEngineConfigurator.setHostVerificationEnabled(false)
client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.SSL_ENGINE_CONFIGURATOR, sslEngineConfigurator);


Создаю ключи


Создаю key.p12

keytool -genkeypair -keystore key.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -storepass MY_PASSWORD -alias KEYSTORE_ENTRY -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 99999 -dname "CN=My SSL Certificate, OU=My Team, O=My Company, L=My City, ST=My State, C=SA" -ext san=dns:mydomain.com,dns:localhost,ip:127.0.0.1


Затем key.jks

    keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore key.p12 \
            -srcstoretype PKCS12 \
            -destkeystore key.jks \
            -deststoretype JKS


Беру приме client java

    import java.net.URI;
    import javax.websocket.*;
    
    import org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLContextConfigurator;
    import org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLEngineConfigurator;
    import org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager;
    import org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientProperties;
    
    @ClientEndpoint
    public class WSSClient {
       private static Object waitLock = new Object();
    
       @OnMessage
       public void onMessage(String message) {
          System.out.println("Received msg: " + message);        
       }
    
       private static void  wait4TerminateSignal() {
          synchronized(waitLock) {
             try { waitLock.wait(); } 
             catch (InterruptedException e) {}
          }
       }
    
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          String socketUrl = "wss://echo.websocket.org";
          WebSocketContainer container=null;
          Session session=null;
          
          try {
             ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();
    
             // System.getProperties().put("javax.net.debug", "all");
             System.getProperties().put(SSLContextConfigurator.KEY_STORE_FILE, "./keystore/key.jks");
             System.getProperties().put(SSLContextConfigurator.TRUST_STORE_FILE, "./keystore/key.jks");
             System.getProperties().put(SSLContextConfigurator.KEY_STORE_PASSWORD, "MY_PASSWORD");
             System.getProperties().put(SSLContextConfigurator.TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD, "MY_PASSWORD");
             final SSLContextConfigurator defaultConfig = new SSLContextConfigurator();
    
             defaultConfig.retrieve(System.getProperties());
    
             SSLEngineConfigurator sslEngineConfigurator = new SSLEngineConfigurator(defaultConfig, true, false, false);
             client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.SSL_ENGINE_CONFIGURATOR, sslEngineConfigurator);
             client.connectToServer(WSSClient.class ,  new URI(socketUrl));
    
             wait4TerminateSignal();
          } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
          finally  {
             if(session!=null) {
                try { session.close(); } 
                catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
             }         
          } 
       }
    }

Ошибки в терминале при запуске  java -cp ".jar:lib/*" WSSClient.java

Кратко

javax.websocket.DeploymentException: SSL handshake has failed

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target


Все

javax.websocket.DeploymentException: SSL handshake has failed
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket._connect(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:380)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket.access$000(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket$1.call(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:212)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket$1.call(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:208)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket.connect(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:226)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientContainer.openClientSocket(GrizzlyClientContainer.java:72)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:647)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3.run(ClientManager.java:696)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:849)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:493)
        at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:299)
        at WSSClient.main(WSSClient.java:50)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.execute(Main.java:419)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:192)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:132)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1351)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1226)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1169)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLUtils.executeDelegatedTask(SSLUtils.java:250)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:684)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLFilter.java:308)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:598)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleRead(SSLBaseFilter.java:310)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1329)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:148)
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:129)
        at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
        ... 32 more


Не получилось tyrus. Наше пример и все получилось c jetty. Только пришлось повозиться с версиями lib. С отключенным ssl.
lib:

jetty-client-9.3.6.v20151106.jar
jetty-io-9.3.6.v20151106.jar
jetty-util-9.3.6.v20151106.jar
websocket-api-9.3.6.v20151106.jar
websocket-client-9.3.6.v20151106.jar
websocket-common-9.3.6.v20151106.jar
websocket-server-9.3.6.v20151106.jar
websocket-servlet-9.3.6.v20151106.jar

import java.net.URI;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketAdapter;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient;

public class WSSClientJetty extends WebSocketAdapter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "wss://localhost:8443/wss"; 

        SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { 
            new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            }
        };
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            sslContextFactory.setSslContext(sc);
            WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient(sslContextFactory);

            client.start();
            Future<Session> fut = client.connect(new WSSClientJetty(), URI.create(url));
            Session session = fut.get();
            session.getRemote().sendString("Hello server");
            session.getRemote().sendString("{\"send_request\":\"Отправляю из java-client-jetty\", \"request_type\":\"{}\"}");
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketConnect(Session sess) {
        super.onWebSocketConnect(sess);
        System.out.println("Socket Connected");
        // System.out.println("Socket Connected: " + sess);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketText(String message) {
        super.onWebSocketText(message);
        System.out.println("Received TEXT message: " + message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
        super.onWebSocketClose(statusCode, reason);
        System.out.println("Socket Closed: [" + statusCode + "] " + reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketError(Throwable cause) {
        super.onWebSocketError(cause);
        cause.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
} 

